# How to sync and update SQLite database table online Android

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite

How to sync the android SqLite table to MySQL DB server? I am using my existing database with android app . Is there any way when click the sync button the database will auto update from online ?  Are there any library classes in android to sync the local db with server db?

Please before make this question as a duplicate see my code and the mentioned question provided by CL is only theoretical but I am facing problem with my app is there is any other example please share your knowledge and any better example you have.

If there is any better solution please help me.

Here is my DataBaseHepler.java adapter

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.SQLException;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        private static String TAG = "DataBaseHelper"; // Tag just for the LogCat window
        //destination path (location) of our database on device
        private static String DB_PATH = "";
        private static String DB_NAME ="SBLdata.db";// Database name
        private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;
        private final Context mContext;

        public DataBaseHelper(Context context, String dbName)
        {
            super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);// 1? its Database Version
            if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17){
                DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
            }
            else
            {
                DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
            }
            this.mContext = context;
        }

        public void createDataBase() throws IOException
        {
            //If database not exists copy it from the assets

            boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();
            if(!mDataBaseExist)
            {
                this.getReadableDatabase();
                this.close();
                try
                {
                    //Copy the database from assests
                    copyDataBase();
                    Log.e(TAG, "createDatabase database created");
                }
                catch (IOException mIOException)
                {
                    throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
                }
            }
        }
        //Check that the database exists here: /data/data/your package/databases/Da Name
        private boolean checkDataBase()
        {
            File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
            //Log.v("dbFile", dbFile + "   "+ dbFile.exists());
            return dbFile.exists();
        }

        //Copy the database from assets
        private void copyDataBase() throws IOException
        {
            InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
            String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
            byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
            int mLength;
            while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer))>0)
            {
                mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
            }
            mOutput.flush();
            mOutput.close();
            mInput.close();
        }

        //Open the database, so we can query it
        public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException
        {
            String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            //Log.v("mPath", mPath);
            mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
            //mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
            return mDataBase != null;
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void close()
        {
            if(mDataBase != null)
                mDataBase.close();
            super.close();
        }


        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {}
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {}


}
```

Please help me?

Comment: If you want to upgrade your database then you need to change database version.

Comment: I am not asking about onUpgrade() method. I am asking about sync with my existing MySQL database with My Sqlite database